# The name form1 does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Inside of my Default.aspx.cs code-behind, I have filled a DataTable _dt with data that was read in from a tab delimited text file. I want to show all contents of _dt to the user when they click a button back on Default.aspx.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

...

        String strLine = String.Empty;
        Int32 iLineCount = 0;
        System.IO.StreamReader srdr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
        do
        {
            strLine = srdr.ReadLine();
            if (strLine == null)
            { break; }
            if (0 == iLineCount++)
            {
                _dt = this.CreateDataTableForTabbedData(strLine);
            }
            this.AddDataRowToTable(strLine, _dt);
        }
        while (true);
        form1.Controls.Add(_dt);
```

But VS is giving me the error: "The name form1 does not exist in the current context". 
form1 does not exist within Default.aspx, but it does exist in Site.Master.

I realize that I probably need to have form1 exist within Default.aspx in order for my code-behind to work, but if I try to do that, and change the ID in Site.master to form2, I get the error
"A page can have only one server-side Form tag." I have to keep the form in place on Site.Master, but I cannot move my code-behind that generates the table to Site.Master.cs

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Where do you think that `form1` is defined?

Comment: @John - it's in the master page, so he has to dig through the controls collections to find it (as noted by OP ;-).

Comment: @fordareh: thanks, but I was asking the OP

Comment: @mate Tried this but it throws the error "cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Web.UI.Control'"

Comment: @JohnSaunders form1 is defined in Site.Master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my data displayed by using [this tutorial](http://www.programmer.bz/Home/tabid/115/asp_net_sql/258/How-to-Read-a-Delimited-Text-File-in-AspNet-Using-OleDb-Including-CSV-or-Tab.aspx) on OleDbDataAdapter.

```
        DataSet dataset = Read_File_Into_Dataset("C:\\TEMP\\", "input.txt");
        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
        dg.DataSource = dataset;
        dg.DataBind();
        this.Controls.Add(dg);

        public DataSet Read_File_Into_Dataset(string fullpath, string file)
        {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM `" + file + "`"; // Read all the data
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection // Connection
          ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fullpath + ";"
           + "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
        OleDbDataAdapter ole = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection); // Load the data into the adapter
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet(); // To hold the data
        ole.Fill(dataset); // Fill the dataset with the data from the adapter
        connection.Close(); // Close the connection
        connection.Dispose(); // Dispose of the connection
        ole.Dispose(); // Get rid of the adapter
        return dataset;
        }
```

Comment: Great! You could see that it was almost mandatory to use "this" :P

Answer (score 0):

The page control (in your case this or this.Page) has a reference to the Master itself, so you have to traverse the control collection to find the Master's child controls - one of which will be the form.  It's not guaranteed to be unique and it's obviously something on the order of M*N, but it did the trick for me for a long time.

You would use it like so:

Control oCtl = SomeUtilityClass.FindControlRecursive(this.Page, "form1");
(remember to check for null here ;-)

I wrote this to handle stuff like that:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Recursive loop to find a control
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rootCtl">Control whose control collection we will begin traversing in search of the 
        ///     given ID</param>
        /// <param name="Id">ID to search for</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootCtl, string desiredCtlID)
        {
            //Make sure this thing exists
            if (rootCtl == null)
                return null;

            //See if it's the one we're after
            if (rootCtl.ID == desiredCtlID)
                return rootCtl;

            //Make sure it has controls to loop over
            if (!rootCtl.HasControls())
                return null;

            foreach (Control oCtl in rootCtl.Controls)
            {
                Control FoundCtl = FindControlRecursive(oCtl, desiredCtlID);
                if (FoundCtl != null)
                    return FoundCtl;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I put your method in my Site.Master.cs and used the following code in my Default.aspx.cs `Control oCtl = SiteMaster.FindControlRecursive(this.Page, "form1");
            oCtl.Controls.Add(_dt);` but VS gives the error "cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Web.UI.Control' - any other advice?

Comment: DataTable is not a control. Why are you trying to add it to the Controls collection?

Comment: @John is right, you may want to try creating a GridView or some other databound control, setting its datasource to your data table and then calling DataBind() and the grid view.

Comment: @fordareh yes, DataBind is what I needed to do.